# Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for 'max_pooling2d_52/MaxPool' (op: 'MaxPool') with input shapes: [?,148,1,32]

Tags: deep-learning

I am getting this Invalid Argument Error Also getting an value error in max pooling layer. dim ordering='th' is also not working. I cant understand why this is happening. pls help someone...Thanx in advance

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(150, 150, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(1024, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())  
model.add(Dense(1024))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.summary()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pooling too many times.

Each time your sample goes through one of your pooling layer, its width and height are divided by two. In the end, you can no longer downscale your sample but you keep trying (apparently at max_pooling_2d_52).

Including the full tracelog would make it easier to interpret your problem though :)

Answer (score 0):

Never make any layer input size lower than its filter size, otherwise it will throw an error.

Size (dimension) of output is calculated as : [(n-f+p)/s]+1 where,

- n : input dimension
- f : filter size
- s : stride
- p : padding

Default padding is zero (also known as VALID padding), as in your case p is default, so p =0

Default stride is one, as in your case s is  also default, so s =1

So formula to calculate Output dimension in your case : n-f +1

also

Max pooling layer reduces dimension by half i.e.  n/2

Now lets break your model layers, calculate
output shape after each layer and see where you are making mistake.

```
model = Sequential()
#  size : 150 * 150 *3 (  given image size)
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(150, 150, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# size :  148 * 148 * 32  ( as : n-f+1 =  150 -3+1  =148 ) 

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# size :  74 * 74 * 32  ( as : n/2 = 148/2 = 74)

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# size :   72 * 72 * 32    (74-3+1 =72)

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# size :36 * 36 * 32    ( 72/2 = 36)

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# size : 34 * 34* 64   (36-3+1 =34)

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# size : 17 * 17 * 64  ( 34/2 = 17)

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# size : 15* 15 * 128   ( 17-3+1 =15)

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# size : 7 * 7 * 128  ( 15/2 = 7)

model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# size : 5 * 5 * 512   (7-3+1 = 5)

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# size : 2* 2* 512    (5/2 = 2)

model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3)))

## now here your n is 2 but f is 3 and n-f  is -1 i.e. negative hence the error


model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(1024, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())  
model.add(Dense(1024))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
```